# Agrupar períodos de datas

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, select

Preciso fazer uma query que retorne todos os registros agrupados em determinados períodos. A tabela contem um tipo date e deve produzir uma saída semelhante a isto:

```
   | Hora  | Quantidade |
-------------------------
01 | 08:00 | 30         |
02 | 08:05 | 28         |
03 | 08:10 | 32         |
04 | 08:15 | 53         |
```

Ou seja:

Na linha 1 foram encontrados 30 registros com a coluna date entre 08:00:00 e 08:04:59, na linha 2 foram encontrados 28 registros com a coluna date entre 08:05:00 e 08:09:59, assim sucessivamente.

Tem alguma forma de agrupar a data por período da forma como descrita na tabela?

PS: O SGBD é Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para agrupar por um intervalo, trunque a data na unidade desse intervalo (minuto, no seu caso), divida pelo total de um dia e some com a data e hora:

```
(trunc(current_date, 'hh')+trunc(to_char(current_date,'mi')/5)*5/1440)
```

Neste [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/086f4c/48/0) eu criei uma tabela com alguns timestamps para teste, na coluna de nome `d`:

```
> select * from datas;

|                     D |
|-----------------------|
| 2017-10-01 08:00:00.0 |
| 2017-10-01 08:01:00.0 |
| 2017-10-01 08:03:00.0 |
| 2017-10-01 08:07:00.0 |
| 2017-10-01 08:08:00.0 |
| 2017-10-01 08:09:59.0 |
| 2017-10-01 08:11:00.0 |
| 2017-10-01 08:11:15.0 |
| 2017-10-01 08:13:00.0 |
| 2017-10-01 08:17:00.0 |
```

Para essa tabela aplico o método acima, tanto para obter o período de cinco minutos quanto para a cláusula `GROUP BY` e para uma janela, a fim de obter o numerador de registros que aparece na sua pergunta:

```
select 
  row_number() over (order by (trunc(d, 'hh')+trunc(to_char(d,'mi')/5)*5/1440)) as " ", 
  to_char((trunc(d, 'hh')+trunc(to_char(d,'mi')/5)*5/1440), 'HH24:MI') as "Hora",
  count(*) as "Quantidade"
from datas
group by (trunc(d, 'hh')+trunc(to_char(d,'mi')/5)*5/1440);

|   |  Hora | Quantidade |
|---|-------|------------|
| 1 | 08:00 |          3 |
| 2 | 08:05 |          3 |
| 3 | 08:10 |          3 |
| 4 | 08:15 |          1 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma eficiente de fazer isso é obtendo os valores por coluna em vez de linhas, uma vez que você já sabe previamente o intervalo de horas desejado.
Dessa forma a consulta fica rápida, pois será passado uma vez só em cada registro. De outra forma (por linha) você precisaria fazer uma subquery e retornar as linhas filtrando cada intervalo de hora em separado, ficando bem mais lento e muito maior o seu select.

```
select 
 sum(case when to_char(campodata, 'hh:mm:ss') between '08:00:00' and '08:04:59' then 1 else 0 end) as "08:00"
,sum(case when to_char(campodata, 'hh:mm:ss') between '08:05:00' and '08:09:59' then 1 else 0 end) as "08:05"
,sum(case when to_char(campodata, 'hh:mm:ss') between '08:10:00' and '08:14:59' then 1 else 0 end) as "08:10"
,sum(case when to_char(campodata, 'hh:mm:ss') between '08:15:00' and '08:19:59' then 1 else 0 end) as "08:15"
from tabela
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Sum(campodata), compodata from tabela group by campodata;
```

o sum vai te dar a soma e o group by vai agrupar;

Comment: Mas e como eu agrupo o campodata a cada 5 minutos por exemplo?, esse select somente vai agrupar datas exatamente iguais

Comment: o group by vai agrupar sim datas exatamentes iguais

Comment: Sim, mas eu quero agrupar datas por período, e não exatamente iguais. dessa forma não vai retornar o que preciso

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309959/oracle-plsql-truncate-datetimes-to-15-min-blocks    uma combinação de trunc e outras functions.